# Batch File - registering all Dll's

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I want to register all dll's under my folder and its subfolder, so I am using the following:

```
    FOR /R "C:\test" %%G in (.) DO (
     Pushd %%G
     for  %%G in ( %%G\*.dll ) do regsvr32 /s %%G
     Echo now in %%G
     Popd )

Echo "Back To Original Directory"
```

Now the problem with this code is it also tries to register files with extension of .dlla, so at that point my batch file is creating problem.

How do I only allow dll files to be registered? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest

```
FOR /R "C:\test" %%G in (.) DO (
 Pushd %%G
 for  %%G in ( %%G\*.dll ) do if /i %%~xG EQU .dll regsvr32 /s %%G
 Echo now in %%G
 Popd )

Echo "Back To Original Directory"
```

Comment: its showing the same result ..!! its trying to register .dlla also

Comment: What happens if you just do `for  %%G in (C:\test\*.dll ) do if /i %%~xG EQU .dll regsvr32 /s %%G`? If you replace `regsvr32 /s` with `echo`, do you see .dlla files too?

Comment: the .dlla files comes up while doing echo also

Comment: OK, the reasoning behind my suggestion is that `if /i %%~xG EQU .dll <someCommand>` would only execute `<someCommand>` if `%%G` has `.dll` extension. Have a look at [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490920.aspx) for more information. In my environment, I was able to reproduce your initial problem and verify that my suggestion fixed it.